# Facebook fake address?

Tags: feature-request, bug, stack-overflow-jobs, companies-page

So, I was taking a look in [Facebook company page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/facebook), and noticed the map. I can tell for sure, there is no Facebook office in the location pointed by the map:

> [image]

Maybe some Facebook employee sipping coffee in the nearby garden, but pretty sure they're not working from there.

As can be seen in [their Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/Facebook-Tel-Aviv-395402830501243/),  the address is Rothschild Boulevard 22 (Tel Aviv, Israel)

> [image]

Can the map in the Jobs company page please be updated with the real address?

Comment: Looks like they delibrately didn't put an exact street address. I'll bring it up with our sales support team.

Comment: @Dean do you mean that's the default for "Tel Aviv, Israel"?

Comment: It certainly looks that way; it resolved to a lat/lon of 32.045101, 34.769711

Comment: http://www.geektime.com/2015/03/22/a-sneak-peek-of-facebooks-new-office-in-tel-aviv/

Comment: @Hans what about it? The real address is mentioned in my question as well.

Comment: Something similar (but worse) happens for the BBC in Birmingham, where the map picks a Birmingham in the wrong country...

Comment: @RowlandShaw good spot, fixed that one

Comment: @RowlandShaw lol, that's much worse!